# Dynamic bootstrap modal, jQuery can not access html elements on first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-modal

So i'm dynamically loading modal from my controller, with product information. Each product has a calculator to calculate price. The issue is when I open the modal the first time, I can remove the disable class from the calculate button. If i open/close/open it will work for every calculator on the page.

products.blade.php

foreach product

```
                                <a
                                    class="btn-icon"
                                    data-toggle="modal" 
                                    data-target="#publicModal" 
                                    data-url="{!! route('public.products.partials.calculator', ['product_id'=>$pp->product->id]) !!}"
                                    data-title="Calculate cost"
                                    data-size="modal-xl" >
                                    <i class="fas fa-calculator"></i>
                                </a>
```

jquery

```
if(
                custSQFT > 0 &&
                custWidth > "0.00" &&
                custLength > "0.00" &&
                totalCost > 0
            ){
                document.getElementById("calc-cost").classList.remove("disabled");
                document.getElementById("calc-cost").classList.add("visible");
                calcValid = true;
            }else{
                $('#calc-cost').prop("disabled",true).addClass('disabled')
                calcValid = false;
            }
```

Modal

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#publicModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    
            if(event.relatedTarget){
              var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
            }else{
             var button = $('#loginButton');
            }
            
            var url = button.data('url') // Extract info from data-* attributes
            var size = button.data('size') 
           
            var modal = $(this)
            if (typeof(size) !== 'undefined') {
             
              modal.find('.modal-dialog').addClass(size)
            } 
            
            modal.find('.modal-body').load(url);
            modal.find('.modal-title').html(button.data('title'))
        
        });

$('#publicModal').on("hidden.bs.modal", function(){
    $(".modal-body").html("");
    $(".modal-title").html("Loading..."); 
});        
</script>
```

So when I open up the modal, fill out the forms, I can console.log that I have made it inside the IF statement, but can not remove the visible class.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are having an issue with replacing the element in the dom with the same id.

I think probably easiest fix would be to add a unique id and capture that specific id to take action within your jquery.

Name the id uniquely, perhaps using the product id:

```
<a id='calc-cost-{{$pp->product->id}}' //... etc
```

Then you have a number of options to identify the current iteration, but I'll illustrate using blade instead of pure JS/Jquery for simplicity:

```
$('#calc-cost-'{{$pp->product->id}}).removeClass('disabled'); //etc
```

Normally, I'd add a data element on the `<a>` and grab the id through jquery to make it a little cleaner ( `$('#calc-cost-'+grabbedIdVar)`), but the above should give you an idea of how to go.

HTH.